# gradle ivy resolver for separate ivys and artifacts

Tags: gradle, ivy

I basically need the functionality of a dual resolver, but can't get this to work the way I want or the way it was working without gradle. My guess is that gradle just can't do what I want here. In this case i want latest to be defined by the ivys it can see in the ivy's repository, which is managed separately from where the artifacts are stored.

Is this possible?

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        // ivys and artfacts are stored separately
        ivyPattern "D:/ivys/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
        artifactPattern "D:/artifacts/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
    }
}

// D:/artifacts/javamail/1.3/mail.jar
// D:/artifacts/javamail/1.4.4/mail.jar
// D:/ivys/toolbox/javamail/1.3/mail.jar

configurations {
    config1
}

dependencies {
    // This configuration fails when there is a newer version of javamail in the artifacts directory
    // but no corresponding ivy in the ivy directory
    config1 "toolbox:javamail:latest.release"

    // This configuration work when I explicitly list the version to resolve
    //config1 "toolbox:javamail:1.3"
}

task build << {
    configurations.config1.each { println it.name }
}
```

Log info (paths are slightly different than the example):

```
16:38:22.570 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver] Resolving configuration ':config1'
16:38:22.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] Creating new in-memory cache for repo 'ivy' [128cfbcee8fb5f2623bb47a30f078d89].
16:38:22.578 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration :toolbox_t1:unspecified(config1).
16:38:22.579 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting dependency :toolbox_t1:unspecified(config1) -> toolbox:javamail:latest.release(dependency: toolbox#javamail;latest.release {config1=[default]})
16:38:22.580 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver] Attempting to resolve module 'toolbox:javamail:latest.release' using repositories [ivy]
16:38:22.581 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] Listing all in file:/D:/UDU/r/tc10.1.2.3.2014102000/src/build/ant/toolbox/javamail/[revision]/ivy.xml
16:38:22.582 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] using ivy to list all in file:/D:/UDU/r/tc10.1.2.3.2014102000/src/build/ant/toolbox/javamail/
16:38:22.583 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] found 1 resources
16:38:22.584 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] Listing all in file:/D:/UDU/tb/javamail/[revision]/javamail.jar
16:38:22.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] using ivy to list all in file:/D:/UDU/tb/javamail/
16:38:22.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] found 2 resources
16:38:22.588 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/D:/UDU/r/tc10.1.2.3.2014102000/src/build/ant/toolbox/javamail/1.4.4/ivy.xml
16:38:22.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/D:/UDU/tb/javamail/1.4.4/javamail.jar
16:38:22.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'toolbox:javamail:1.4.4' in repository 'ivy'.
16:38:22.593 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.ResolvedConfigurationDependencyGraphVisitor] Attaching :toolbox_t1:unspecified(config1) to its parents.
16:38:22.597 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.TransientConfigurationResultsBuilder] Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in C:\Temp\2\gradle2080536410688129731.bin. Wrote root :toolbox_t1:unspecified:config1.
16:38:22.600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':build'
16:38:22.601 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :build FAILED
```

Comment: I have no idea whether this can be made to work.  But why aren't you resolving against Maven Central, or a local Ivy/Maven instance?

Comment: This particular artifact repository is for 3rd party artifacts and belongs to another process/system that is strictly controlled and very large, it contains native libraries, and much more, so maven central is not an option for several reasons. We have been able to map into it using Ant and Ivy resolvers and patterns. We manage the ivys with the product source because we are not allowed to add them to the toolbox repo.

Comment: Why is the ivy missing? Can't/shouldn't you fix this? What's the *exact* error message/output? Question seems specific to `latest.release`, which should be reflected in the title.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':build'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':config1'.
   > Could not resolve toolbox:javamail:latest.release.
     Required by:
         :toolbox_t1:unspecified
      > This module has not been resolved.

Comment: The file paths in the log are totally different from those configured in the build script. Are you sure the logs come from this build script?

Comment: Yes the log is different, I noted that. I was trying to provide a generic example, but the real thing is only different in the root paths to the artifactPattern and ivyPattern.